# copying data from multiple files and adding to different files

Tags: linux, perl, file

okay, i am not sure whether this is even possible or not..I may sound stochastic...
There are around 250 files with names as 
Eg:1

`1_0.pdb,1_60.pdb,1_240.pdb,....50_0.pdb,50_60.pdb,50_240.pdb.....` having some data.

Now for each of the above file there is a another file of same name....just prefix file is added...Like:
E.g:2

`file1_0.pdb,file1_60.pdb,file1_240.pdb,....file50_0.pdb,file50_60.pdb,file50_240.pdb.....` again having some data.

is there a code possible that can copy data from each file from first example and paste it to its corresponding file in example2..? like from 1_0.pdb to file1_0.pdb...I hope iam not random and more clear...

Comment: How do you want to merge the contents of `1_0.pdb` and `file1_0.pdb`? Should the contents of `1_0.pdb` be appended to `file1_0.pdb` or should it replace what was originally in `file1_0.pdb` or ...???

Comment: there shouldnot be any replacement...I just want to append contents of 1_0.pdb to file1_0.pdb

Comment: Do it in the shell: `for x in [0-9]*.pdb; do cat $x >> "file$x"; done`

Answer (score 3):

With perl you could do something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my @filenames = qw(1_0.pdb 1_60.pdb 1_240.pdb);

for my $filename (@filenames) {

    open(my $fr, '<', $filename) or next;
    open(my $fw, '>>', "file$filename") or next;

    local($/) = undef;
    my $content = <$fr>;

    print $fw $content;

    close $fr;
    close $fw;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of listing all filnames in

```
my @filenames = qw(1_0.pdb 1_60.pdb 1_240.pdb);
```

you could do something like

```
my @filenames = grep {/^\d+_\d+/} glob "*.pdb";
```

Comment: `print $fw for <$fr>` is even shorter.

Comment: But it's not line-by-line mode, and so uses more memory.

Comment: There is a problem...the code seems to add data from first file (say 1_0.pdb) to every file with a name file*.pdb....
I, whereas want to append data of one file to its corresponding file
i.e from 1_0.pdb to only file1_0.pdb and not to any other file*.pdb

Comment: @TLP: Ah, I thought you meant that slurp mode was unnecessarily verbose. I see what you mean now. Kanika, are you sure that the exact code I posted above does that?

Comment: yes,very sure...and that file names are already defined,i can't use the code on different files.Like it wont work for 50_120.pdb

Comment: i think it should not append to all the files. One guess is, you may have included all the file names to @filenames array

Comment: @kanika I think Aki's assumption must be right, and I thought it was implied that you would put only the files to copy from in the `@filenames` array, and all of them; not just the three I used to exemplify.

Comment: I tried to use the program to add data from a single file(part1.pdb) instead of multiple files to files named File12_0.pdb,File25_60.pdb etc..Can you please spot the error..?
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my @filenames = qw(part1.pdb);

for my $filename (@filenames) {

open(my $fr, '<', $filename) or next;
open(my $fw, '>>', grep {/File\d+_\d+/} glob "File*_*.pdb") or next;

local($/) = undef;
my $content = <$fr>;

print $fw $content;

close $fr;
close $fw;
}

Comment: @kanika: The problem is that you're trying to open file handles for appending on a list of files with `open(my $fw, '>>', grep {/File\d+_\d+/} glob "File*_*.pdb")`. If the file you're trying to write to is named **Filepart1.pdb** use `open(my $fw, '>>', "File$filename")` instead.

Comment: @kanika: I misread your question. You want `my @filenames = qw(part1.pdb);for my $filename (@filenames) {open(my $fr, '<', $filename) or next;local($/) = undef;my $content = <$fr>;my @outfiles = grep {/File\d+_\d+/} glob "*.pdb";for my $outfile (@outfiles) {open(my $fw, '>>', $outfile) or next;print $fw $content;close $fw;}close $fr;}`

Answer (score 1):

Give this code a try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (glob "*.pdb") {
  next if ($file =~ /^file/);

  local $/ = undef;
  my $newfile = "file$file";

  open(my $fh1, "<", $file) or die "Could not open $file: " . $!;
  open(my $fh2, ">>", $newfile) or die "Could not open $newfile: " . $!;

  my $contents = <$fh1>;

  print $fh2 $contents;

  close($fh1);
  close($fh2);
}
```

If you want to overwrite the contents of the files rather than appending, change `">>"` to `">"` in the second `open` statement.

Comment: There is a problem...the code seems to add data from first file (say 1_0.pdb) to every file with a name file*.pdb....
I, whereas want to append data of one file to its corresponding file
i.e from 1_0.pdb to only file1_0.pdb and not to any other file*.pdb

Comment: @kanika Actually, I've tested the code, and it only adds data to the corresponding file.  In the loop, `$newfile` is set to the name of the current file preceded by the word "file," and the second `open` statement opens only that file.

Answer (score 0):

This shell script will also work

```
foreach my_orig_file ( `ls *.pdb | grep -v ^file` )
set my_new_file = "file$my_orig_file"
cat $my_orig_file >> $my_new_file
end
```

Comment: this is a shell script, "`" is a backtick (left side to 1 in keyboard)

Comment: yes,but my linux says:

shell.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'hell.sh: line 1: `foreach my_orig_file ( `ls *.pdb | grep -v ^file` )

Comment: ah! got it. Your default shell is not c shell. write this code in a file and run "tcsh file_name"

Comment: if you dont have tcsh, try csh

Comment: ok...i did that...but there is a problem...it works on a single file..not on multiple files...

Comment: it should work on all *.pdb files, that are not starting with file. may be you can debug it by running the command ls... in xterm directly

Comment: No need to grep: `for x in [0-9]*.pdb; do cat $x >> "file$x"; done`